# Null pointer exception when adding quad to geometry in jME 3

Tags: java, null, geometry, java-me

i'm using the j Monkey Engine 3 to build a custom voxel engine. In the Block.java class i create an array of geometry objects to wich i want to assign quad meshes. This code returns null pointer exception:

```
    faces = new Geometry[6];

    Mesh q = new Quad(0.2f, 0.2f);

    if(q == null)
    {
        System.out.println("q is null"); ----> this doesn't occure
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        faces[i].setMesh(q.clone());   -------> this still gives null pointer
    }
```

Maybe it's just a stupid mistake. If you need more code I can post the whole java class.

Answer (score 1):

I think `faces` is an empty array. So `faces[i]` is null.
Try something like this first:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    faces[i] = new Geometry();
}
```

Comment: btw faces[i].setMesh(new Quad(0.2f, 0.2f)); also throws a null pointer exception

Comment: @user2466076 Maybe you should accept my answer if it was useful for you. Thanks!